# R - Better performance for sum with multiple conditions

Tags: r

Having two dataframes:

1. `URLSMMG` with 374 observations
2. `pagesVisited` with 99120    observations

I use the following function to `sum` all values from `pagesVisited` that satisfy two conditions, placing the result in a new column in `URLSMMG`:

```
# Calculate pageviews from MMG
for (i in 1:nrow(URLSMMG)) {
        URLSMMG$pageviewsMMGClick[i] <- sum(pagesVisited[
        which(pagesVisited[,11] == URLSMMG$URLWithoutParameters[i] &
        grepl(paste0("ic=", URLSMMG$Code[i]), pagesVisited$evar3) == TRUE),3])
}
```

Measuring the function execution time, it says the function needs about 4 minutes to end. I am happy with the result, as the output is the expected, but I am not sure if I am doing the calculation using the fastest method. Does someone knows another way of doing that in less time?

Comment: Thx! Trying right now with a fresh data frame, because in the previous attemps the performance was not much better (far away from your 30-60s estimation). Data comes from a call to Adobe Analytics API, so it may take about 10 minutes to come :). I will respond in your answer as soon as the execution time is displayed

Comment: All values are unique :(, so, no performance with this approach

Comment: Is it feasible to extract the relevant part after `"ic="` from `evar3` to its own variable in `pagesVisited` or is the `grepl` really necessary here?

Comment: @ZheyuanLi yeah `length(unique(URLSMMG$URLWithoutParameters)) = 374`

Comment: Instead of a loop, a join-filter-summarise approach would likely be much faster. First, left join the variable to be summed from `pagesVisited` to `URLSMMG` on your first condition. Second, filter the resulting data on your second condition. Finally, calculate the sum of your variable of interest in each group defined by `URLWithoutParameters`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should be much faster:

```
## temporary vectors
pagesVisited11 <- pagesVisited[, 11]
URLWithoutParameters <- URLSMMG$URLWithoutParameters
Code <- URLSMMG$Code
evar3 <- gsub("ic=", "", pagesVisited$evar3)
pagesVisited3 <- pagesVisited[, 3]
pageviewsMMGClick <- numeric(nrow(URLSMMG))

## only touch vector inside loop
for (i in 1:nrow(URLSMMG)) {
  cond1 <- pagesVisited11 == URLWithoutParameters[i]
  cond2 <- grepl(Code[i], evar3)
  pageviewsMMGClick[i] <- sum(pagesVisited3[cond1 & cond2])
  }

## append new column to URLSMMG in the end
URLSMMG$pageviewsMMGClick <- pageviewsMMGClick
```

Comments:

1. For memory efficiency, do not touch data frame inside a loop. This is why I extract all relevant vectors before the loop, and only use vectors inside the loop;
2. I have removed the `== TRUE` and `which`, as there is no need;
3. I have also dropped `paste0` inside the loop; instead, I removed `"id="` from `evar3` outside the loop. In this way, you avoid the expensive `paste0` during each iteration.

Comment: Thx for your answer! There is not much improvement (311s vs 323s from my loop). Maybe is just my laptop. However, I will accept your answer because (1) the performance is better and (2) the code is more readable. I need to make more sum of this type, all with different and more complex conditions, so you show me a way to make it more understable for future collaborators.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some variables, primarily for clarity but in the case of
`pv_code` hoisting a call out of an iteration so that it is performed once
instead of 100's of times.

```
pv_url <- pagesVisited[, 11]
pv_code <- sub("ic=", "", pagesVisited$evar3)
pv_click <- pagesVisited[, 3]
```

Each page visited belongs to a group

```
grp <- match(pv_url, URLSMMG$URLWithoutParameters)
```

We make this a factor, and include all URLWithoutParameters as
levels. This makes the code robust to URLs that do not appear in
`pv_url`

```
grp <- factor(grp, levels=seq_len(nrow(URLSMMG)))
```

We're only interested in some rows

```
keep <- pv_code == URLSMMG$Code[grp]
```

We'd now like to filter `pv_click` and sum by group

```
URLSMMG$pageviewsMMGClick <-
    sapply(split(pv_click[keep], grp[keep]), sum)
```

(the corresponding line in the original code `URLSMMG$pageviewsMMGClick[i] <- ...` copies the entire date frame each time a row element is updated, and is very inefficient; it would be better to pre-allocate a temporary variable `click = integer(nrow(URLSMMG)`, fill during the loop `click[i] <- ...`, and update URLSMMG once at the end, or simply use `sapply()` instead of worrying about pre-allocation ad fill).

As a function we have

```
fun <- function(url, url_code, pv_url, pv_code, pv_click) {
    stopifnot(!any(duplicated(url)))
    grp <- factor(match(pv_url, url), levels=seq_along(url))
    keep <- pv_code == url_code[grp]
    unname(sapply(split(pv_click[keep], grp[keep]), sum))
}
```

Here's a short test for correctness

```
url <-     c("A", "B", "C")
url_code <- c( 1,   1,   1)

pv_url <-   c("A", "A", "A", "C")
pv_code <-  c( 1,   1,   2,   1)
pv_click <- c( 5,   6,   7,   8)
```

with output

```
> fun(url, url_code, pv_url, pv_code, pv_click)
[1] 11  0  8
```

For performance, here's data of the same size as in the original question

```
url  <-     as.character(1:374)
url_code <- sample(3, 374, TRUE)

pv_url <-   sample(url, 99120, TRUE)
pv_code <-  sample(url_code, 99120, TRUE)
pv_click <- rep(1, 99120)
```

and the timing

```
> system.time(xx <- fun(url, url_code, pv_url, pv_code, pv_click))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.036   0.000   0.035
```

This appears to be a 10,000x speedup compared to the original.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach based on data manipulation operations instead of looping. The `data.table` package provides significant speed-ups when working with large data.

Note: in the sample code I assume that the names of columns 3 and 11 of `pagesViewed` are `clicks` and `url`, respectively.

```
library(data.table)
library(stringi)
library(dplyr)

# use data.table for speed
dt1 <- data.table(URLSMGG, key = "URLWithoutParameters")
dt2 <- data.table(pagesVisited, key = "url")

# generate the values used for the grepl-equivalent stri_detect_fixed
dt1[, ic_code := paste0("ic=", Code)]

viewsums <- dt2[dt1  # join the page data to the matching urls
    ][stri_detect_fixed(evar3, ic_code),  # keep rows where ic_code is found in evar3
      list(views = sum(clicks)), by = "url"]  # sum the clicks for each url

# join the summed views to the url data
URLSMGG <- left_join(URLSMGG, viewsums, by = c("URLWithoutParameters" = "url")) %>%
    mutate(views = ifelse(is.na(views), 0, views))
```

Using the same test data as Martin Morgan, here's the performance of this approach. I included two different scenarios, one where the `grepl`-like search of `evar3` is required, and another without it.

```
# preparing the testing data (succintly written by Martin Morgan)
urls <-     as.character(1:374)
url_code <- sample(1:3, 374, TRUE)

pv_url <-   sample(urls, 99120, TRUE)
pv_code <-  sample(url_code, 99120, TRUE)
pv_click <- rep(1, 99120)

# and the corresponding data.frames
URLSMGG <- data.frame(URLWithoutParameters = urls, ic_code = url_code)
pagesVisited <- data.frame(url = pv_url, evar3 = pv_code, clicks = pv_click)
```

The first implementation where a string search is performed:

```
f1 <- function()
{
    # use data.table for speed
    dt1 <- data.table(URLSMGG, key = "URLWithoutParameters")
    dt2 <- data.table(pagesVisited, key = "url")

    viewsums <- dt2[dt1  # join the page data to the matching urls
        ][stri_detect_fixed(evar3, ic_code),  # keep rows where ic_code is found in evar3
          list(views = sum(clicks)), by = "url"]  # sum the clicks for each url

    # join the summed views to the url data
    left_join(URLSMGG, viewsums, by = c("URLWithoutParameters" = "url")) %>%
        mutate(views = ifelse(is.na(views), 0, views))
}
```

The second scenario where we can simply directly join on both the url and code:

```
f2 <- function()
{
    # use data.table for speed
    dt1 <- data.table(URLSMGG, key = c("URLWithoutParameters", "ic_code"))
    dt2 <- data.table(pagesVisited, key = c("url", "evar3"))

    # join the page data, matching urls and codes, and then sum clicks by url
    viewsums <- dt2[dt1, list(views = sum(clicks)), by = "url"]

    # join the summed views to the url data
    left_join(URLSMGG, viewsums, by = c("URLWithoutParameters" = "url")) %>%
        mutate(views = ifelse(is.na(views), 0, views))
}
```

And finally the performance:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(f1(), f2())
#     Unit: milliseconds
#      expr       min        lq     mean    median        uq       max neval
#      f1() 61.148200 62.919882 64.68540 64.396362 66.160684  70.65989   100
#      f2()  7.532806  7.784006 10.40422  7.979846  8.579847 175.83275   100
```

*(These timings are on an Intel Core i5-4460, and may or may not be comparable to other results)*